# Native App Links inside HTML email

Tags: html-email, url-scheme

Im designing a set of Modular Email Blocks for a project and while I'm familiar with HTMl and the mobile web I'm not so familiar with the limits of HTML in email.

Can Apps be opened from content inside a HTML email ? example, Can i Link to my Twitter bio, Facebook page, Trigger a SMS, etc just like you can do from the web using URL schemes ?
Is this limited to just the open of the Apps or can we go further, like have a follow button inside the email or populate the SMS subject line and recipient.

If anyone has any experience or live example that would be amazing

Comment: this is a little demo site using the URL scheme to open Apps, check it out on a mobile device.
http://www.marktmcewan.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you’re using URL scheme links (i.e, `twitter://`), it depends on the email app the link is being opened in. For example, the default iOS mail app works, but the Gmail app doesn’t. The functions supported via URL scheme depends on the specific app. Here's a list: http://handleopenurl.com.

Sticking with URL schemes default iOS apps (SMS, Mail) is probably reasonably safe, but anything third-party will show a nasty "Cannot Open URL" if the app is not installed when the link is opened. Apple introduced Universal Links with iOS 9 to help fix that issue. If the app supports Universal Links ([partial list](http://www.jackivers.me/blog/2015/9/17/list-of-universal-link-ios-9-apps)) then you just use a regular link and the app will open automatically if installed and fall back to the web page if not.

If you're building your own app and want to support this, [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I work with the team) can handle all of these annoying edge cases for you.